# Is there an effective way to perform the advanced “faceted” filtering for the array data (with Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, faceted-search

I have an array:

```
var arr = [
["a", "b", "d"],
["k", "b", "n", "a"],
["k", "a", "e", "c"],
["k", "b", "e"],
["b", "c"]
]
```

I want to extract all values occurring only in subarrays which contain both "a" and "b". For the above example, these would be `["d", "k", "n"]`.
 Of course, there is an obvious way to achieve the result:

1. Create new array/object, let's name it `result`.
2. Iterate over `arr`. For each subarray, check if it contains all items of `["a", "b"]` - if yes, then add all its items (maybe except "a" and "b", but it doesn't matter) to `result` (but before adding, we might want to check if an item with the same value already exists in `result`); if no, then skip.
3. If we did not check our items before adding, then remove all duplicates from `result`. If `result` is sorted alphabetically, it should now be `["d", "k", "n"]`.

The problem is that this way seems to be **too** slow and ineffective, especially if I have many subarrays in `arr` and not much different values: I will be forced to repeat the process each time when `["a", "b"]` has been modified!

It would be easy to construct a structure like this:

```
 var s = [
{value: "a", siblings: ["b", "c", "d", "e", "k", "n"]},
{value: "b", siblings: ["a", "c", "d", "e", "k", "n"]},
{value: "c", siblings: ["a", "b", "e", "k"]},
{value: "d", siblings: ["a", "b"]},
{value: "e", siblings: ["a", "b", "c", "k"]},
{value: "k", siblings: ["a", "b", "c", "e", "n"]},
{value: "n", siblings: ["a", "b", "k"]}
]
```

But if I now filter all objects that contain every value of `["a", "b"]` in its `siblings` key, I get `["d", "e", "k", "n"]`, which is wrong.

So, I want to ask: is it possible to build some smart, “indexed” structure that will look like

```
  var s = [
{value: "a", data: indexdata1},
{value: "b", data: indexdata2},
{value: "c", data: indexdata3},
{value: "d", data: indexdata4},
{value: "e", data: indexdata5},
{value: "k", data: indexdata6},
{value: "n", data: indexdata7}
]
```

such that when I do `someFunc(s, ["a", "b"])`, it returns `[{value: "d"}, {value: "k"}, {value: "n"}]`? Anyway, what can be considered as an **effective** way of solving this problem in Javascript? Are there existing libraries with such functionality?
Note that this problem differs from what [eikes.github.io/facetedsearch](http://eikes.github.io/facetedsearch/) does (or I cannot find the way to modify its code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proposal with a different approach. Instead of a view to the single items/letters, organize an object `s` with the indices of the arrays of the found letters.

Then sharp it by counting and filter only the letters with a count of the given search length (`c`). Build a new object `r` with the letters from the remaining indices of `c`.

Delete the given letters from `r`, get the keys, order them and return the result.

```js
function x(s, array) {
    var c = {}, r = {};
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        s[a].forEach(function (b) {
            c[b] = (c[b] || 0) + 1;
        });
    });
    document.write('<pre>c: ' + JSON.stringify(c, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
    Object.keys(c).filter(function (a) {
        return c[a] === array.length;
    }).forEach(function (a) {
        arr[a].forEach(function (b) {
            r[b] = true;
        });
    });
    document.write('<pre>r: ' + JSON.stringify(r, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        delete r[a];
    });
    document.write('<pre>r: ' + JSON.stringify(r, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
    return Object.keys(r).sort();
}

var arr = [
        ["a", "b", "d"],
        ["k", "b", "n", "a"],
        ["k", "a", "e", "c"],
        ["k", "b", "e"],
        ["b", "c"]
    ],
    s = arr.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        a.forEach(function (b) {
            r[b] = r[b] || [];
            r[b].push(i);
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

document.write('<pre>s: ' + JSON.stringify(s, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>result: ' + JSON.stringify(x(s, ['a', 'b']), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work! Storing values in Object.keys... yes... this approach is better...